# Rails: Normal log doesn't print out after inserting custom middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print out all request from client. So I write a custom middleware:

```
class Logger
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)

    headers = env.select {|k,v| k.start_with? 'HTTP_'}
    .map {|pair| [pair[0].sub(/^HTTP_/, ''), pair[1]].join(": ")}
    .sort

    request_params = env['rack.input'].read

    puts "Request: #{env["REQUEST_METHOD"]} #{env["PATH_INFO"]} #{headers} #{request_params}"

    @app.call(env).tap do |response|
      status, headers, body = *response

      puts "Response: #{status}"
      puts "Headers: #{headers}"
      # puts "Response:"

      # body.each do |line|
      #   puts line
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

After that, I insert to `application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, ::Logger
```

Request is printed out fine. The only problem is all other logs (such as activerecord log hasn't existed anymore). Please help me figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are naming your class `Logger` which is already the name of the [Ruby standard lib `Logger` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) which is used by the Rails logger i.e. you are overriding the `Logger` class (the `initialize` method in particular) and breaking Rails logging.

Name your logger class something else like `MyRackLogger`.